# CSS selector with period in ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The HTML spec allows for periods (.) in an id:

`<img id="some.id" />`

However, using a CSS ID selector rule will *not* match correctly:

`#some.id { color: #f00; }`

The CSS spec for [ID Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) does not mention this case. So I assume it is using the combination of a tag name and [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)? For example, a CSS rule of `a.className` would apply to all anchor tags (`<a>`) with a class name of `className`, like `<a class="className"></a>`.

Is it possible to have an external CSS file rule that references an HTML element by its id that has a period in it?

I expect not since the CSS spec specifies that a CSS "[identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)" does not include the period as a valid character. So is this a fundamental mismatch between HTML and CSS specs? Is my only alternative to use a different type of CSS selection? Can anyone smarter than I confirm or deny this?

(I would remove the period from the HTML id attribute to simplify things, but it is a system-generated id, so I don't have the ability to change it in this case.)

Comment: You could say that this is a fundamental mismatch between HTML and CSS. However, as they're two different languages, it is not expected that they match up; an HTML identifier is an HTML identifier while a CSS identifier is a CSS identifier. Also, CSS can style other languages too, not just HTML (although granted, CSS was made for HTML in the beginning).

Comment: Also `#some.id` is using the combination of ID and class selector.

Comment: Is the ID the only attribute that you have as style hook? I know it's a little off-topic, but I'm wondering why you'd want to use an ID instead of img or a class (if available).

Comment: @Jayx RE "Why use an ID instead of img (tag) or a class?" It varies for lots of reasons and situations. But in this case, a specific element needed styled, not all images on the page. A class could have been used if the HTML could be modified, but in this case it couldn't be modified as it was generated by a system beyond our control.

Comment: May all people who used dots in ids/classes may have their code sent to hell. Discovering this dumbness in 2022, after 12 years doing HTML/CSS. There should be a law against such thing.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

After digging through the specs some more, I found the CSS spec does allow for [backslash (`\`) escaping](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) like most languages.

So in my example, the following rule would match:

```css
#some\.id {
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Good research job. There should be more Q&A like this, no like „write my code instead of me“.

Comment: nice research. I just ran across this in a large enterprise application im working on. I was totally stumped and never seen it before. whats the point of making an id with a period in it??

Comment: @Anthony: There isn't a specific reason to put a period in an HTML id attribute. I guess sometimes authors just want to? Maybe in some cases it could be bleed over from the underlying implementation systems that might use periods in the server-side code's identifiers for form processing? I'm sure everyone that does has their own reasons; but there is no HTML/CSS reason to include them.

Comment: Thank you, I was having problems with OpenLayers since it does use dots in its ids. For example: "OpenLayers.Control.Attribution_7". I guess it helps with the internal code where they can have the javascript variable name be the same value as the id itself.

Comment: I've run across the same problem @Anthony pointed, working with Hybris.

Comment: I was considering adding a new question and writing my own answer, but decided to just comment here. If you are using the Stylus preprocessor, you need to use two backslashes, e.g., `#some\\.id` to escape the special character. The first backslash is consumed by Stylus, leaving the remaining backslash in the compiled CSS, which achieves the desired result described in this answer.

Comment: Fun fact: this doesn't work in Chrome dev console using $$("..")

Comment: This seems to work in attribute selectors like `[click\.delegate*='Edit']:hover` as well!

Comment: @FDM - yes it does but you have to use \\, as with the Stylus preprocessor referenced by markrian

Answer (score 32):

You could also use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) like this:

```css
[id='some.id'] {
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: This may work in some browsers, but I have seen errors thrown for attribute selectors as well. You can still escape the `.`, as `\.` though.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using id, you can also use document.getElementById() which checks the id value as a normal string and not a CSS selector.
e.g. the following works too:

```
const myElem = document.getElementById("some.id");
```

The only drawback is, you can't limit the scope of search, like you could with querySelector e.g. someElement.querySelector().
but since Ids should always be unique, a document wide search with id is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the note, but the question was specifically requesting a CSS-based solution due to the common situation that when you can't change the HTML (to remove the period from the id, common in some frameworks, CMS packages, etc.) then there's a good chance you can't add your own JavaScript either.