# Reference to multiname in CSS (e.g. 'name.secondname')

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS selector with period in ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id)

HTML:

```
<input id="name.secondname" ... >
```

How should I define a CSS style for 'name.secondname' ?

```css
#name.secondname {
  ...
}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: It is possible, but i suggest avoiding it if possible to avoid confusion.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the dot with `\`

For example:

```css
#name\.secondname {

}
```

Comment: There are escape chars in CSS? Why no book teaches that?

Comment: Its there but best avoided. Probably thats why.

Answer (score 6):

You have to escape it like so:

```css
#name\.secondname
```

I should note this appears to have been asked before: [CSS selector with period in ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id)