# .addClass and .removeClass not firing

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I have a small page I am testing some jquery out on and one of the elements generated is:

`<i class="fa fa-arrow-up personstatus" id="status.3140" style="color: #00ff00;" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

I am using jquery to do some modifications:

```
$('.personstatus')
        .click(function() {
            var color = $(this).css("color");
            var personId = $(this).attr('id').replace('status.', '');
            $.get('changestatus/' + personId,
                function(response) {
                    if (color == 'rgb(0, 255, 0)') {
                        alert('Down');
                        $('#status.3140').removeClass('fa-arrow-up');
                        $('#status.3140').addClass('fa-arrow-down');
                        $('#status.3140').css('color', '#ff0000');
                    } else {
                        alert('Up');
                        $('#status.' + personId).removeClass('fa-arrow-down');
                        $('#status.' + personId).addClass('fa-arrow-up');
                        $('#status.' + personId).css("color", "#00ff00");
                    }
                    alert('Finished');
                });
        });
```

It is hitting the alert lines as I would expect, but it is not applying the `.removeClass` `.addClass` or the `.css` at all.

I have another section of jquery code where these work fine:

```
$('.showdetails')
        .click(function() {
            var personId = $(this).attr('id');
            document.getElementById('currentid').innerHTML = personId;
            $.get('loadperson/basic/' + personId,
                function(response) {
                    document.getElementById('persondetails_table').innerHTML = response;
                    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
                    $('#persondetails_basictab').addClass('active');
                    $('#person_details')
                        .lightbox_me({
                            centered: true
                        });
                });
        });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: how is someone clicking on a hidden element?

Comment: @depperm - Its not a hidden element, it is a font-awesome icon

Comment: You should try using breakpoints or a debugger statement in lieu of alerts. Then you can look that those DOM values that you are trying to manipulate and see if they are actually available. My guess is that your string replace might be the culprit.

Comment: I think it's because of the . in "#status.3140" you should use "-" instead if I am correct I think the jquery assumes that the "." is a class instead of an id so it assumes that you have a class="3140"

Comment: I think you can escape the `.` to make it use it as part of the ID. `$("#status\\.3140")`

Comment: Thanks to Swordfish, and confirming Daren and Barmar, the '.' was my issue.  As I stepped through the debugger, it was using the '.' as a string splitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with ID. You cannot name it "status.3140". It is explained in more detail here: [CSS selector with period in ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id)

This won't work:

```css
#status.3140 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="status.3140">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

This will work:

```css
#status\.3140 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="status.3140">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

However, I highly recommend to avoid periods in IDs. Better change it to `id="status-3140"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Swordfish0321, and confirming @Daren Delima and @Barmar, the '.' was my issue. As I stepped through the debugger, it was parsing the string using the '.' as a string splitter.  I was able to escape the '.' and all works.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Hi Keith, it's best to just mark the answer that worked for you as accepted which tells users that answer was correct and leave it at that, not add another answer too.