# CSS adjacent selector + :after pseudo element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble selecting an element, and I must do it without editing the pre-existing HTML below:

```
  <div class="neoncrm-radio-button">
     <input type="radio" name="membershipEnrollment.membershipTerm" value="4" onclick="showConsolidate(this.form)" id="membershipEnrollment.membershipTerm_4" class="neon2Field2" attr="0">
     <label class="neoncrm-radio-label" for="membershipEnrollment.membershipTerm_4">Membership Name</label>
```

I would like to add the text "($50)" after the label, so that it looks like "Membership Name ($50)."

The problem is, I only want to add the text to the label for the input with the id #membershipEnrollment.membershipTerm_4." I can't use the div class "neoncrm-radio-button" to help select since the class is used for many other inputs.

I've tried doing

```
#membershipEnrollment.membershipTerm_4 + label:after { content:"$50"}
```

but it doesn't work. Any help or insight as to why this doesn't work, and possible solutions, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you need to escape the period:

`#membershipEnrollment\.membershipTerm_4 + label::after { content:"$50" }`

Found from this answer: [CSS selector with period in ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id)