# JavaFX css id selector with dot (full stop) in name

Tags: java, css, javafx, css-selectors

I am working on a JavaFX project where node ids have to be unique. This is implemented by naming them with a "full path" name, e.g. "myPane.button1". When I try to select one of these elements in a css stylesheet I cannot figure out how to write the id selector. Here is an example application with two buttons named "the.button" and "thebutton":

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CssTest extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.setId("the.button");
        b1.setText("BUTTON1");

        Button b2 = new Button();
        b2.setId("thebutton");
        b2.setText("BUTTON2");

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2);
        vbox.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");

        final Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }    
}
```

The css file is

```
#the\.button {
    -fx-graphic: url("Keyboard.png");
}

#thebutton {
    -fx-graphic: url("Keyboard.png");
}
```

[Escaping the dot should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id), but I cannot get JavaFX to match the element. I could not find restrictions on the element id in the JavaFX doc, both for `Node.setId` and in the JavaFX css reference, but if it is not allowed it would be a good argument to change the names.

[The JavaFX CSS reference says that](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph)

> JavaFX Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is based on the W3C CSS version
>   2.1 with some additions from current work on version 3. JavaFX CSS also has some extensions to CSS in support of specific JavaFX
>   features.

I would conclude that this means that a valid W3C CSS file is also a valid JavaFX CSS file. And then defines the id as

> Each node in the scene graph has an id variable, a string. This is
>   analogous to the id="..." attribute that can appear HTML elements.
>   Supplying a string for a node's id variable causes style properties
>   for this node to be looked up using that id. Styles for specific ids
>   can be specified using the "#nodeid" selector syntax in a style sheet.

[For HTML, the id attribute's naming convention is](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

> Naming rules: Must contain at least one character Must not contain any
>   space characters In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

So there is no restriction on the id, but I cannot write a selector that selects it. I think this is a bug.

Comment: For me the keywords used and what makes the whole difference is *based on*. It later explains that it has **some extensions**.  Then, **analogous** doesn't mean equals nor identical.

Comment: @Mansueli Then there is the question what is actually accepted by the JavaFX CSS parser. Many things are not explicitly defined in the doc and just vaguely described with the reference to the CSS standard. There is a list of limitations, but then it also says that only syntax specified in the document should be expected to be accepted. Strictly, this means that selectors are not accepted because they are not defined in the doc...

Comment: That much I agree with you, not a great example of documentation.  I believe it is one of the reasons Stack Overflow started [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation). But escaping chars is probably something overlooked by Oracle and they probably won't even bother to implement since their document is vague enough that allow they avoid compliance.  I would love in say JavaFX 10 they say `we support CSS3 with some extension`. We can hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Parse your CSS, you'll see:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         CSSParser cssParser =  new com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser();
         Stylesheet s = cssParser.parse("#the\\.button {\n" +
"    -fx-graphic: url(\"Keyboard.png\");\n" +
"}\n" +
"\n" +
"#thebutton {\n" +
"    -fx-graphic: url(\"Keyboard.png\");\n" +
"}");
         System.out.println(""); //add a breakpoint here
    }
```

That there is only one rule for the id `thebutton` and there is two ways to understand why:

- One is looking at the [source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/css/parser/CSSParser.java#CSSParser.Term)
- The other is paying attention to a warning in the [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introlimitations)

Which I quote below:

> While the JavaFX CSS parser will parse valid CSS syntax, it is not a fully compliant CSS parser. **One should not expect the parser to handle syntax not specified in this document.**

*Emphasis mine*

Which means if you are trying something that belongs to the CSS standard, but isn't listed on the Oracle's documentation you are going to get a hard time.

Comment: The document also says that JavaFX CSS is an extension of W3C CSS and then defines the id in a way that "a.b.c" is a valid id. Selectors are defined as CSS2 selectors, so I think it should be supported. The listed limitations do also not contain my case. I am not saying it is a huge problem as it can be easily avoided. It would be nice to just document it.

Comment: @jens Perhaps, I misread. But for me they make a point of being their own take on CSS with `JavaFX Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is *based* on the W3C CSS version 2.1`. *Based* is very different from *extension* AFAIK.