# CSS selector with hash and dot combination

Tags: css

Today I looked strange CSS selector and just curious to know where it would work? I am working in production maintenance and code is quite old. CSS selector start with hash and DOT. I googled it and couldn't find any reference.

```
#.wrapper #Step1 ul.font_div li.first {
    position: static!important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

**Note: It's not an invalid selector for sure. But as I mentioned the code is quite old. they intentionally put it for IE5 hack. It works in IE5. It escape # and only read .wrapper.**

Comment: the id is ".wrapper" maybe ? but it should be #\.wrapper .... Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id

Comment: It looks like a typo, is it doing anything when you check browser dev tools?

Answer (score 2):

That `#.` is not a valid selector. They might have changed an id to a class and forgot the remove the `#`.

Comment: Indeed. You can combine ID and Class selectors in this way: `#id.class1.class2`

Comment: Yes @Marian07, but not like `#.name`... They probably forgot to put the `id name` or something...