# Depth of Field Effect?

Tags: html, css

Just trying to create a modal that zooms and blurs the background back. Based on avgrund by hakim https://lab.hakim.se/avgrund/

Now it has nesting modals also with the help of  @deathshadow over at codingforums.

Here is the current state:
https://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/1jz0q3xk/19/

```html
    <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modalsOff" class="toggleAll" hidden checked>
    <!--1 Text-->
    <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modal1" class="toggle" hidden>
    <div>
        <label for="toggle_modalsOff"></label>
     <div>
         <label for="toggle_modalsOff">&#x1F5D9;</label>
      <label for="toggle_modal1.1">
          <img class="inarticle" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e00000/000000"/></label>
       <p>Modal 1</p>
            </div>
     </div>
    <!--1 Images-->
    <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modal1.1" class="toggle" hidden>
    <div>
     <label for="toggle_modalsOff"></label>
     <div>
      <label for="toggle_modal1">&#x1F5D9;</label>
      <img class="popup" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/e00000/000000"/>
      <p>
       Caption Image 1
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--2 Text-->
    <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modal2" class="toggle" hidden>
    <div>
     <label for="toggle_modalsOff"></label>
     <div>
      <label for="toggle_modalsOff">&#x1F5D9;</label>
      <label for="toggle_modal2.1">
       <img class="inarticle" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0034de/000000"/></label>
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
       </p>
      <label for="toggle_modal2.2">
       <img class="inarticle" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/218f63/000000"/></label>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--2 Images-->
    <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modal2.1" class="toggle" hidden>
    <div>
     <label for="toggle_modalsOff"></label>
     <div>
      <label for="toggle_modal2">&#x1F5D9;</label>
      <img class="popup" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0034de/000000"/>
      <p>
       Caption Image 1
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modal2.2" class="toggle" hidden>
    <div>
     <label for="toggle_modalsOff"></label>
     <div>
      <label for="toggle_modal2">&#x1F5D9;</label>
      <img class="popup" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/218f63/000000"/>
      <p>
       Caption Image 2
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <!--3 Text-->
      <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modal3" class="toggle" hidden>
      <div>
       <label for="toggle_modalsOff"></label>
       <div>
        <label for="toggle_modalsOff">&#x1F5D9;</label>
         <p>
          Modal 3
         </p>
         <label for="toggle_modal3.1"><img class="inarticle" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/708f22/000000"/></label>
       </div>
      </div>
    <!--3 Images-->
    <input type="radio" name="modal" id="toggle_modal3.1" class="toggle" hidden>
    <div>
     <label for="toggle_modalsOff"></label>
     <div>
      <label for="toggle_modal3">&#x1F5D9;</label>
      <img class="popup" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/708f22/000000"/>
      <p>
       Caption Image 1
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <!--
    Main Page
    -->
    <div id="content"><div id="contentInner">
     <!--
      We need the double-wrapper as flex centering screws up scrolling and position on small displays, so the outer wrapper has to provide our
      scrollbars and the inner one handles the scaling / blur.
     -->
     <h1>Depth of Field Test</h1>
    
    
     <ul class="modalSelect">
      <li><label for="toggle_modal1">
      <p>Modal 1</p></label></li>
    
      <li><label for="toggle_modal2">
      <p>Modal 2</p></label></li>
    
      <li><label for="toggle_modal3">
    
      <p>Modal 3</p></label></li>
     </ul>
    
    
    <!-- #contentInner, #content --></div></div>
```

Now, what I am trying to do is:
by clicking the nested modal link, everything should be pushed back again and blurred - like simulating receding layers/depth of field.

I've attached an image to explain this:
[image]

Here is a large version: https://ibb.co/LNB83jm

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do this is by using a combination of the `filter: blur(3px);` and the `transform: scale(0.8)` css-property.

You can see a working example on this fiddle I just created:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const background = document.getElementById('background');
const foreground = document.getElementById('foreground');

let  modalIsVisible = false;

container.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);

function toggleModal() {
  if (modalIsVisible) {
   hideModal();
    modalIsVisible = false;
  } else {
   showModal();
    modalIsVisible = true;
  }
}

function showModal() {
 background.classList.add('blur');
  foreground.classList.remove('hidden');
}

function hideModal() {
 background.classList.remove('blur');
  foreground.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#container > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  line-height: 2em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#background {

  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#foreground {
  z-index: 2;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="background">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</div>

<div id="foreground" class="hidden">
  I'm visible now!
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i quite like the functionality of the first attempt as i can do many modals and the nesting is working on two levels. just need the blur/scale property to work!

Comment: Can't you add them to the elements you want to fade out dynamically with javascript, like I did in the example?

Comment: also it is all css

Comment: I don't think this problem can be solved with only CSS. I could be wrong, but why overcomplicate instead of using a few lines of javascript.

Comment: i guess i am just a noob with javascript.... how can i add multiple divs and then nesting and that effect?! :S

Comment: No need to be so critical of yourself. Also, I noticed that you have some html `id` tags that have perdiods in the value (id="toggle_modal1.1"). Beware, as this might result in some [Gotcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming))s when you are [starting to reference them in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id).