# Display an element which is inside an array of an JSON object

Tags: jquery, html

I can display an element of my JSON object but if it's inside an array then I got stuck.

Here is my code:

```
   $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: api_url,
            // url: mock_url,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: adminPrefData,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                // callback(res);
                $('#module').text(res.module);  // i get this
                $('#networkId').text(res.networkId); // and this
                $('#adminPrefInfo.type').text(res.adminPrefInfo.type); // nothing happens on page
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#info').html('<p>An error has occured</p>');
            },
        });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="content">
        <div class="nav-link-content home">
            <h1 class="text-center" id="module"></h1>
            <div class="text-center" id="networkId"></div>
            <div class="text-center" id="adminPrefInfo.type"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JSON I get:

```
{"module":"dnd","networkId":1,"adminPrefInfo":[{"id":1,"key":"teszt","value":"teszt","defValue":"teszt1","type":"checkbox","isActive":true}]}
```

Comment: can you add the json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS selector with period in ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id)

Comment: I edited it and changed adminInfoList to adminPrefInfo that wasnt matching with the name in my json. Now i dont get any error but still dont show me the element inside the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is because you have a period in the `id` attribute of the HTML element. You need escape it in the jQuery selector with `\\`. The second issue is that `adminPrefInfo` is an array. As such you need to access it by index, then get the `type` property. Try this:

```
$('#adminInfoList\\.type').text(res.adminPrefInfo[0].type);
```

Comment: Looking at the JSON, I don't see a property with a dot in it...

Comment: The dot is in the CSS ID

Comment: @HereticMonkey true - the object strucutre was added after I wrote this answer. I've since updated it.

Comment: @Kerk now you've added your object structure I can see the second issue is because `adminPrefInfo` is an array. I've edited the answer to give you a correct example

Answer (score 0):

There was a small mistake for **type** which is/was available at 0 index

```
const ajaxResponse = {
  "module": "dnd",
  "networkId": 1,
  "adminPrefInfo": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key": "teszt",
      "value": "teszt",
      "defValue": "teszt1",
      "type": "checkbox",
      "isActive": true
    }
  ]
};

console.log(ajaxResponse);
console.log(ajaxResponse.module); // dnd
console.log(ajaxResponse.networkId); // 1
console.log(ajaxResponse.adminPrefInfo); //object type: "adminPrefInfoType"
console.log(ajaxResponse.adminPrefInfo[0].type); // checkbox
```

Answer (score -1):

Its because `adminPrefInfo` is an array of objects. You need to loop through it in order to access `type` property like below:

```
res.adminPrefInfo.map(adminInfo => console.log(adminInfo.type));
```