# change font size of all of the verbatimTextOutput in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing R shiny with multiple pages.
Each page has a verbatimTextOutput.

However, I can only change the fontsize of the first verbatimTextOutput, which is recommended_model.
I can not control the font size of the second verbatimTextOutput(recommended_model2.2).

Please give me a favor and find out what's the problem.
Thanks for helping :)

The following is the ui code:

```
    navbarMenu(HTML("<span style='font-size:130%'>2. TRAINING+TESTING</span>"),
           
           tabPanel(title=HTML("<span style='font-size:130%'>2-1. Model Analysis</span>"),
                    
                    sidebarPanel(
                      tags$head(
                        tags$style(HTML(
                          "label { font-size:16px;}",
                          "#recommended_model{ font-size:150%;}",
                          "#validation_text{font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;}",
                          
                        ))
                      ),
                      #something in the sidebar....
 

                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      
                      tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel(HTML("<span style='font-size:130%'>Analysis Results</span>"),

                                 verbatimTextOutput("recommended_model"),
                                 
                        )
                      )
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel(title=HTML("<span style='font-size:130%'>2-2. Prediction</span>"),
                    
                    sidebarPanel(
                      tags$head(
                        tags$style(HTML(
                          "label { font-size:16px;}",
                          "#recommended_model2.2{ font-size:150%;}"
                          
                        ))
                      ),
                      
                      #something in the sidebar......
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel(HTML("<span style='font-size:130%'>Prediction Results</span>"),
                                 
                                 verbatimTextOutput("recommended_model2.2"),
                                 
                                 
                        )
                      )
                    )
           )
           
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. [CSS selector with period in ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310090/css-selector-with-period-in-id)

Essentially your id here: `#recommended_model2.2`, has a period in it and periods are used for identifying classes in CSS not IDs.

I would recommend using an ID that doesn't include a special character or at the very least not a `"."`. Alternatively, if you are dead set on using the ID above. This may work.

```
tags$style(HTML(
   "label { font-size:16px;}",
   "#recommended_model2\.2{ font-size:150%;}" # include backslash before "."
))
```